# Get image of icon from css in a Angular app

Tags: css, icons

how can I retrieve the image of an icon from the given css below? (see the pic)

[image: chrome dev screenshot]

This icon is in a 3th party npm lib in an angular application, but I cant find any trace of this image by finding svg, png, jpg file or finding by 'music' keyword under the node_modules dir ... no any help just content: "\e94e"

Thanks for the answers in advance.
Csaba

Comment: `e94e` is a Unicode value of a character in the file of font family `Line`. Essentially a coordinate of a position in a table where character `xy-i-music` can be found. Search online for 'icon font file' or  'custom font file'. How to create. Dig into the well known 'FontAwesome' icons. Comes both as separate SVGs as well as a font file.

Comment: Thank you, so this icon is encoded in a font file, many thanks.